# How to get array inner component data from laravel blade file of format

Tags: arrays, json, laravel

> problem on accessing array data from laravel blade file

```
    @foreach($connbid as $conaccept)
        {{$conaccept->contributer_id}}<br>
             @foreach($conaccept['accept'] as $acceptpost)
                    {{ $acceptpost->bidpost_id }}<br>
                    {{ $acceptpost->customerpost->vehicle_booking->id }} //problem in accessing this 
                                                                           data from blade
             @endforeach
    @endforeach
```

> the raw json is as:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "contributer_id": 2,
    "post_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2019-10-23 16:31:52",
    "updated_at": "2019-10-23 16:31:52",
    "accept": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "user_id": 1,
        "customerpost": {
          "id": 1,
          "customer_id": 1,
          "vehicle_booking": {
            "id": 1,
            "vcustomeraccept": {
              "id": 1,
              "created_at": "2019-10-23 16:15:42",
              "updated_at": "2019-10-23 16:15:42",
              "customeraccept": null
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

If `$conaccept` is an array, try to change

```
$conaccept['accept']
```

on

```
$conaccept->accept
```